# How can I write group by in jira jql?

Tags: jira, jql, jira-rest-java-api

I am working on few reports in which I am taking data from jira using REST API. For searching purpose, I am using JQL. I want to use group by tag for few of my queries. How can I use group by tag in JQL?

Comment: With pure JQL you can't. It is marked as "WontFix" - https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-23516

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out-of-the box you can't. You might achieve this by:

- use [jira remote api](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Remote+API+Reference) to get 2 jql outputs and group them as you wish
- [create your own JQL function](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Remote+API+Reference)
- [query the DB](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA041/Database+Schema) directly ([example](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA041/Example+SQL+queries+for+JIRA))